# How do I change the output of the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, format

How do I left justify the output of the string? I am trying to print first email, on the next lines print the next, etc

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>

        //The email list
        var emailList = ["adam@yahoo.edu\n", "henry@yahoo.edu\n", "john@yahoo.edu\n", "sally@yahoo.edu\n", "adam@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "myhome@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "hunger@yahoo.edu\n", "madison@yahoo.edu\n"];

        //remove the yahoo extension
        var emailUserHash = emailList.reduce(function(emailUsers, email, i) {
            var username = email.slice(0, email.indexOf('yahoo'));
            if(!emailUsers[username]) emailUsers[username] = true;
            return emailUsers;
        }, {});

        //call the emailUserHash function
        var emailUsers = Object.keys(emailUserHash)

        //sort the email list
        emailUsers.sort();

        //output the list
        document.write(emailUsers.join(', '));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the current output? the "\n" is actually breaking the lines?

Comment: @Clyff I am using Tryit Editor to edit code and look at the output.

Comment: Just replace in your `document.write(emailUsers.join(', '));` by `document.write(emailUsers.join(',<br />'));`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify your join()

Using '/r/n' will not help you here

```
document.write(emailUsers.join('/r/n'));
```

So you can use 'br' This will work for sure.

```
document.write(emailUsers.join('</br>'));
```